# Theming a node reference field in a template file

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I have two content types:

- Course
- Subject

The Course nodes have a field reference field which references a Subject node.

In the Course node display, I want to have access to the variables from the corresponding Subject node. I've set the field to render as 'rendered node', but I need to rearrange the fields from both nodes to construct a tabbed interface out of all of the fields available.

What's the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a template, as suggested above, you force your drupal to use subject-node.tpl.php to display "subject" nodes, no?
To display fields or data from the referenced node you could create a view that returns fields and everything you want, setting a "nid" contextual filter.
So, in your "course template" you have to include the view, in this way:

```
print views_embed_view('view_name', 'views_display', $node->nid);
```

You can also use Context module to display this view.

Comment: Thank you. I this is exactly what I want. Yes you were right, I don't want to create a subject.tpl file, as I'm going to construct a complex tabbed page out of a mixture of variables. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use theme_render_template() function like below.

```
$subject_node_object = node_load('node/' . $node_id_from_ref_filed);// Pass your node ref here.
// Use below code in your course node template.
print theme_render_template(drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOUR_THEME_NAME') . 'PATH_TO_TEMPLATE/subject-node.tpl.php', $subject_node_object);
```

You need to create a template for you subject content type fields.